# Android change TextView color of Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I've been trying to change the Spinner TextView color. I need to do it programmatically. I have my personal Adapter and resource view. (I don't want to change the pop up sipnner text color, only the text that is shown on the users layout when somenthig is selected)

This is my code:

```
PersonalArrayAdapter spAdapterInfraccion = new PersonalArrayAdapter(getContext(),
            R.layout.item_spinner,
            infraccionList);

spinner.setAdapter(spAdapter);
```

item_spinner.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<co.my.app.utils.CustomTextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

This is how I've try it, but returns null.

```
CustomTextView text = (CustomTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
text.setTextColor(getContext().getColor( R.color.black ));
```

Comment: Can't tell without seeing what `view` is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this :-

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { 
int index = adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition();
((TextView) spinner.getSelectedView()).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue));
```

Hope it may help you. :)